# javascript doesn't recognize id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a button on my php page to hide and unhide a section on my page.
I have this javascript function:

```
      function toggle_filters(){
    var x = document.getElementById("filters");
    var displayState = x.style.display;
    if(displayState == "none")
    {
        displayState = "block";
    }
    else {
        displayState = "none";
    }
}
```

and i have this html code:

```
<section id="buttons">
    <button id="filter_button">Filters</button>
</section>
<section id="filters">
    <form>
        <select>
            <option>1st option</option>
            <option>2nd option</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</section>
```

(it is a simplified version)

The problem is that my browser gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Here is a jsfiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/90wkwn65/2/

I searched the internet but I can't find an answer.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's preferred to toggle the *display* property between "none" and "" (empty string) so that when visible, the element adopts its default or inherited style. It's more generic than setting it to "block", which doesn't suit many elements. Oh, and the error is probably because the function is running before the element exists in the page.

Comment: It's a typo, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var displayState = x.style.display;
```

`displayState` is just a variable that contains a string.  It has zero connection to `x.style` any more.

So, when you then do this:

```
displayState = "block";
```

All you're doing is change the value of the `displayState` variable - no connection at all to the `style` object of `x`.  So you need to assign to a property on the actual style object in order to actually change the style.

---

Also from the code in your jsFiddle, you need to change this:

```
document.getElementById("filter_button").onclick = toggle_filters();
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("filter_button").onclick = toggle_filters;
```

When you put `()` after a function name that function is executed immediately and the return result would be applied as the onclick handler.  In this particular case you just want to assign a function reference as the onclick handler so you pass only the function name without parens after it.

---

Applying those two changes, this code works in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyL6ehef/):

```
function toggle_filters(){
    var x = document.getElementById("filters");
    if(x.style.display == "none")
    {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
document.getElementById("filter_button").onclick = toggle_filters;
```

---

The above code works in the jsFiddle, but if your real code is still getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Then, that is because you're running the `document.getElementById("filter_button")` line of code too soon (probably in the `<head>` section).  Instead, you must run that line of code only AFTER the DOM has been loaded.  The simplest way to do that is to move that `<script>` tag to right before the `</body>` tag.  See this answer ([pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)) for much more detail on this issue.

Comment: The same as the other answer, with this code I get this error: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null_

Comment: @LorenzoDeBie - please read the last section of my answer.  Your real code is not working the same as the jsFiddle so you need to make a correction to the location of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks!

Comment: Short attention span…

Answer (score 1):

You can store element.style as a reference in order to alter the css properties, but you cannot store element.style.display as a reference in the same way.

Also when assigning an onclick function, do not use parenthesis, otherwise the function will execute instead of being assigned to the click event.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/90wkwn65/3/))

```
  function toggle_filters() {
      var x = document.getElementById("filters");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  document.getElementById("filter_button").onclick = toggle_filters;
```

Comment: With this code I get another _error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null_